# What are Live Credentials?

Tags: plaid

What are live credentials when working with accounts?  I've done some searching and can't find an answer.

The following image is from the Plaid API Docs:  https://plaid.com/docs/quickstart/

[image]

Comment: You have to request access at PLAID. Then you will get credentials for "development", which you can use instead of the user_good and  pass_good defaults for sandbox mode.

Answer (score 2):

Test you integration with live credentials means you can test the real bank account in the development environment. In development, you can test max 100 real bank accounts (Live credentials) for testing purpose. After 100 accounts, you can test anymore real accounts in development.

So do your testing in sandbox environment with test credentials(user_good, pass_good) for the banks and once you are confident about your integration switch to development and test with real bank accounts.

https://dashboard.plaid.com/overview

Sandbox - Use test credentials and account data to build out and test your Plaid integration
Development - Test your Plaid integration with real credentials and account data for up to 100 Items
Production - Connect unlimited bank accounts and access our full range of products; all requests are billed

Note : You need to request plaid for development access for your keys.

Comment: I think you mean "After 100 accounts, you *cannot* test amymore real accounts in development"

Comment: Yes. For development use sandbox environment. Once everything is tested in sandbox, switch to development and test with real bank account.

Answer (score 1):

Like the list indicates, there are multiple environments. The sandbox environment uses example (mock) credentials (referred to as 'test credentials'), while the development environment uses actual credentials (referred to as 'live credentials'). Live in this sense means credentials that can actually be used, hence why you need to request access.